# Unable to mock HTTPS request using Mountebank

Tags: https, mountebank

In order to mimic HTTPS request we are using our own created certificate (created using OpenSSL) and trying to create an imposter using this certificate value and its private key.
However we are unable to hit the application url in browser using this certificate after authenticating it , gives an error of authenticity.
Can anyone please suggest us the way as how to proceed for mimicing HTTPS request using the SSL certificate?
Refer below imposter created

```
{  "port": 5555, "protocol": "https",  "name": "proxy",  "stubs": [    {
     "responses": [
       {
         "proxy": {
          "to": "https://www.demoblaze.com",
           "key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nEUVo5KSEFq93UeMr3B7DDPIz3LOrFXlm7clCh1HFZhQ=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
           "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nXOdprCdUUXzSoJWCCg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
         }
       }
     ]    }  ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the certificate is self-signed, not trusted by your Certificate Authority (CA). Let's Encrypt gives you self-service (and free!) access to fully trusted certificates; I'd recommend going through their documentation to create a cert.